# freeze music player across website

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, youtube-api, soundcloud

I have a website with youtube and soundcloud embedded songs. Upon the stream of one of these embedded media files I would like the song to keep playing regardless of moving to different pages in the site. How can I achieve this? It would also be great if a music controller came up in the footer.

I am embedding using auto_html gem

```
<% if micropost.url.include? 'youtu' %>
  <%= auto_html(micropost.url) {youtube(:width => 540, :height => 190)} %>
<% end %>

<% if micropost.url.include? 'soundcloud' %>
  <%= auto_html(micropost.url) {soundcloud} %>
<% end %>
```

I haven't written any code for a music player yet. Can I even get both embeds to play through a custom music controller? Or I can use youtubes and soundclouds.

Comment: add some of your code atleast...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make an <audio> file play continuously on all pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612120/how-do-i-make-an-audio-file-play-continuously-on-all-pages)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html5 audio tags, you can bind click event to play button, and then stop all audio plays, but `$(this)`