# play background music in website which continuously while page navigations

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

In my site i need to play background music where it should be continuous while navigating to other pages, my following code starts the music from the beginning when I navigate to another page.

```
<embed src="assets/audio.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true">
</embed>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but can I ask *why*?

Comment: I want the music to run throughout the site it should not restart while I am navigating to another page

Comment: No, I mean why do you want to continuously play music? Auto playing background music went out of style a long time ago and is pretty poor UX especially if you aren't presenting controls to the user.

Comment: If you need to use 1999 technology and have a frameset or iFrame or a popunder window, then perhaps you want to rethink your approach

Comment: Here is similar solution :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612120/how-do-i-make-an-audio-file-play-continuously-on-all-pages

Comment: Kindly refer this answer, it is very usefull:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612120/how-do-i-make-an-audio-file-play-continuously-on-all-pages/15613752#15613752