# Stop current song once new song is played from new div content - howler js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, howler.js

So what I want to achieve actually is the same as the other music players that even if I change pages I will still have the music continue to play. well I already achieved that by changing only the div content on button click. but my problem now is that once I change pages let's say to a new playlist. the player play/pause button and next/prev will not work anymore and once you play the music on the playlist it wont stop the current song playing. I am btw using codeigniter and codes are correct and working it just seems like once I change content it will apply new player javascript and the previous one will be hidden.

I wan't to post the code but all the codes are very long. well I just want to ask is there any way to dynamically load a certain div without loading the js files again? and the player will continue to function same way as it was once on the previous page

Comment: where is your code, have you heard about node.js

Comment: I've heard about node js but was using php since it's a php project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612120/how-do-i-make-an-audio-file-play-continuously-on-all-pages